# Rss error in first line of xml : not well-formed (invalid token)

Tags: rss, xml

I'm having a problem with my **rss feed**.

Validator.w3.org is not accepting it, saying ***not well-formed (invalid token)* on line 1**.

It seems that the name of the website appearing between `<?xml ?>` and `<rss>` might be causing the problem.

Column 54 is the end of the site name.

[image]

I cannot find where i can remove it...
Any idea ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have additional code active there add this string inside the feed and destroy the XML markup. The hook on this place is `rss_tag_pre` (see https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/b3b8942dfcb451eddb5559b63c1043fce5d9449e/wp-includes/feed-rss2.php#L21).

Deactivate all plugins, use a default Theme, and then, step by step, activate it again to identify the source for this problem. Alternative search about the `wp-content` directory for the hook `rss_tag_pre`.

Also, make sure there is no custom RSS feed in place in your `functions.php`.

Comment: No files refer to  rss_tag_pre   in the   wp-content... I have even commented the    do_action( 'rss_tag_pre', 'rss2' );  in wp-includes   with no effect...

Comment: Have you tried to deactivate all plugins, the theme - to identify sure, that is not a problem from addons?

Comment: I found the problem.  My mistake.  There was a custom rss feed on the website that wasn't supposed to be there.  So I removed it and it was fine.   But still, no trace of outputing any blog name.  I don't like this type of ghosting system.  Thanx for the support.  Not sure i should leave the question then.  What do you think ?

Comment: Ok I've just added "make sure there is no custom rss feed in place in your function.php".

Comment: However, the `functions.php` is a part of the Theme. If you test with a default Theme you should remove this error.